# My Ubuntu 22.04 LTS laptop is stuck on "Wi-Fi connecting." Any ideas?

Tags: internet

When I was downloading, my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS laptop suddenly disconnected from the Wi-Fi. When I tried to reconnect, it was stuck on "Wi-Fi connecting" and after a while it said "Wi-Fi not connected". I tried to restart my laptop and I even rebooted my router but nothing worked. And the weird thing is that my laptop connects to the mobile hotspot but not to the Wi-Fi. Does someone have any ideas?